# how to set a folder as a root path when running html without a server

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am going to share a lesson on HTML format for students who will run it on their local computers. Lets say, the student copied the study folder on desktop. and executed it. The address bar looks like this.

```
file:///C:/Users/Student1/Desktop/study/reading/step3/001.html
```

I have style.css file

```
<link rel="Stylesheet" href="study/css/style.css" />
```

when I run the file I get this error

```
001.html:9 GET file:///C:/Users/David/Desktop/study/reading/step3/css/style.css net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

when I try to load the css from root path like this

```
<link rel="Stylesheet" href="/study/css/style.css" />
```

I get this error

```
001.html:9 GET file:///C:/study/css/style.css net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

There are more than 400 html files and 80 folders. It would take more than 3 hours to specify the .css and .js files for each file in each folder. I want to set a root path for each file no matter in what folder they are. So, basically after setting the folder **study** as a root path, if the file is loaded from

> d:\downloads\learn\english\ielts\study\academic\reading\practice_test\003.html

using `<link rel="Stylesheet" href="/study/css/style.css" />`  css should be loaded from

> d:\downloads\learn\english\ielts\study\css\

and if the file is loaded from

> c:\Users\Student1\Desktop\study\academic\reading\practice_test\003.html

using `<link rel="Stylesheet" href="/study/css/style.css" />`  css should be loaded from

> c:\Users\Student1\Desktop\study\css\

if I would appreciate any feedback on how to set the study folder as a root path.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `../` to go up a directory from the current when providing the path. Try this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../study/css/style.css" />
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. Sorry my question wasn't very detailed. when the html file in study/master/academic/reading/practice_test/003.html then I will need to use `../../../../css/style.css` I can not do this for each file because there are more then 80 sub folders and more then 400 html files.

Comment: I'm afraid there's no alternative. You cannot set an absolute `<base />` url on a local file system because every machine's file structure is different.

Comment: when I use `<base href="/Users/David/Desktop/" />` it loads the css an js file correctly but I can not add this line to 400 files either.  what about javascript? is it not possible to set a base href using javascript? I can add it  to one of the js file and all html files will load it.

Comment: You can set a `<base />` element using JS - but it is pointless. `/Users/David/Desktop` is the valid location on your machine, but for me it would be *completely* different.

Comment: can u write an example? base href can be change as long as it works.

Comment: You're missing the point - you don't know what to change it *to*.

Comment: okay can I use two base href? for example 
<head>
<base href="http://www.sitename/study/">
<base href="/users/david/desktop/study/">
</head>

Comment: No you can use only one base element, but again you miss the point. Say I install your HTML on my machine right now, in any random folder. How do you know what absolute base URL to set? ***The only solution is to use relative paths with `../`*** I know this may be a lot of work at the end of a project, but there is zero alternative in your case.

Comment: okay. I give up. I will edit all the files manually to show to correct path. it would take me a lot of time. I just thought that it is possible to set some virtual root path with jquery and run it offline from any folder.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming 001.html is in study folder and you have a folder called css in that study folder so then your path should be:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
```

So HTML is in study/reading/step3/ and the CSS is below that in study/css/

so your link will be

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/style.css" />
```

If you want to use a single path no matter what you'll have to run your files from a local server on your machine such as wamp or Xampp that way if your root folder is study
you can access your css folder anywhere within that folder by:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css" />
```

Comment: Note that the HTML is in `study/reading/step3/` and the CSS is below that in `study/css/`

Comment: I edited my question. Is it not possible to set a root path using javascript?

Comment: @david83 no there's no way you can set a root path with javascript, as I already said you'll have to use a server. The other alternative is to use an absolute path to the css file which will be `C:/Users/David/Desktop/study/css/style.css` but this is not ideal and you'll have to change it for each pc.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to have arisen because the files were written/tested using a server where links like `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css" />` worked because they came from a server. Technically that kind of link is a relative URL with an absolute path (it is not an absolute URL). The problem arises on the students' machines because they are not using a server.

Potential solutions include

1. Rewrite the reading material so it does not use absolute paths. A common technique for doing this is to place resource files for images, scripts, css etc. in subfolders of the HTML files. But this would involve major changes to the existing structure of the HTML package download.
2. An alternative would be to have students run a server on their machine, such as a static express server running on node.js. Students would have to download the HTML files to a specific folder on their machine and access the material using a `localhost` address. Whilst somewhat more complicated than downloading a zipped ebook, I am assuming these are IT students who can be taught how to install a local server, but perhaps not!